# Highcharts Sunburst changing color on level change

Tags: angular, highcharts

Is it possible to dynamically change colors of layers in sunburst chart on level change?

For example, this is our chart: [image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-KURkV1WJhCGrf9__zpBavNnI9gGPvPk/view?usp=sharing]

when clicking on continent like Asia we will get something like this [image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hj_CvQ1iUsmHafFGTysfE_vllUOE405D/view?usp=sharing],

on clicking on Southern Asia chart will be changed like [image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qWDAPl8OXPwGLn6YW8kI-4k8tKQJ0ipq/view?usp=sharing]

I tried to dynamically update levels

```
this.update({
            levels: [{
              level: 1,
              levelIsConstant: false,
              dataLabels: {
                filter: {
                  property: 'outerArcLength',
                  operator: '>',
                  value: 64
                }
              }
            }, {
              level: 2,
              colorByPoint: true
            }, {
              level: 3,
              colorByPoint: true
            }, {
              level: 4,
              colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: 0.5
              }
            }]
          })
        } else {
          this.update({
            levels: [{
              level: 1,
              levelIsConstant: false,
              dataLabels: {
                filter: {
                  property: 'outerArcLength',
                  operator: '>',
                  value: 64
                }
              }
            }, {
              level: 2,
              colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: -0.5
              }
            }, {
              level: 3,
              colorByPoint: true
            }, {
              level: 4,
              colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: 0.5
              }
            }]
          })
```

but it didn't work as expected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality is not supported by default in Highcharts and requires several customizations. I preapared and example that presents how you can achieve the needed result, but it is limited in drill up to max level.

```
H.seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype.drillUp = function() {
    this.drillToNode('0.0');

    this.update({
        levels: levelsOptions
    });
}


H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype, 'onClickDrillToNode', function(proceed, e) {
    var point = e.point,
        length = point.node.children.length;

    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    if (length) {
        this.update({
            levels: [{
                level: point.node.level,
                colorByPoint: true
            }, {
                level: point.node.level + 1,
                colorByPoint: true
            }]
        }, true);


        this.showDrillUpButton('The world');
    }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/evdjaqhc/